# How to delete account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deletion

How to delete account? (thirty character limit)

Comment: I don't believe you can delete your own account (see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/option-of-deleting-an-account), but moderators can delete your account for you. Would you like me to?

Comment: @Qiaochu yes. i have had two helpful answers to one question. I hope that stays on the record.

Comment: @Qiacochu Give me a one hour window starting now. There is something I have been meaning to add in the discussion to one of my questions. After that, you may do it at your convenience.

Comment: @J.M For the Legendre Polynomial question, yes. For the Delta function, no. The answer restated what I'd done in my notes, maybe I was unclear. Anyway @Willie Wong's comment hit the nail directly, so I did not pursue it further, instead going to his reference in detail. Also, thank you very much for answering a different question of mine. Your answer was detailed and it was important personally, because it explains where I was stuck. It is the one I am editing presently, an alternative method, so have a look when I'm done. Feel free to comment and correct even if I'm not around :-)

Comment: @sam How a question is received here often depends crucially on how it is formulated. For example, your recent question might have been better received in the form: My friend has xxx health problems but has strong mathematical aspirations. However some folks are discouraging him from studying math because they claim that no successful mathematicians had xxx problems. Can you help me to encourage my friend by providing examples of successful mathematicans who overcame such physical challenges? In other forums I've seen questions of this form for xxx = autism, dyslexia, etc.

Comment: For the moderators: In the interest of full disclosure, I used to go by the username "Approximist" (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/7253/approximist) Then I recently decided to use a new account with my real name and ID. Since I am no longer continuing this field, both seem pointless excercises. I shall leve a comment from other account later today  when I have time so it may be killed as well.

Comment: @Qiaochu Verifying above, requesting deletion.

Answer (score 8):

You might just delete your last question instead.

Comment: Although after looking at samanwita's recent question, I agree with your answer. This does not answer the question, even though if the motivation for it probably comes from the bad reception that the question had. +1 nevertheless =)